# Python - How to add new column and add value to each file and then club to one

Tags: python

Adding new column to all the file that are there in the folders

Example : Folder EU -> Folder LOH --> File - DB_LOH_2019_20.csv , DB_ABC_2019_20.csv
      folder AP -> Folder SGH--> File - DB_SGH_2019_20.csv ,DB_EDF_2019_20
      Folder US -> Folder NYK --> File - DB_NYK_2019_20.csv,DB_KEH_2019_20

Code should pick the file from moving to the folder and pick one file DB_LOH_2019_20.csv 
add new column as SITE =LOH and 
DB_ABC_2019_20.csv add new column as SITE= ABC
same for folder B file as SITE= SGH and Folder C , SITE= NYK , once this is done then club all file into one dataframe.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to add the new column name and value to each file ????